# Unknown operation of bracketed expressions

Tags: linear-algebra

I've come across Linear Interpolation as a method for working out a programming need I have. Several examples I've seen show a algebraic expression that my not sure how to operate:

[image]

[image]

What are the operations needed at point 1, 2, 3?

Please excuse my language/definition ignorance (and tag selection), it's been a *long* time since I've had to do this sort of maths!

Comment: multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a multiplication. In mathematics, it is normally denoted by juxtaposition of arguments.